# Sandbox Not Working

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I keep getting the following from PayPal sandbox when needing to make an Adaptive payment:

We can't process your payment right now, so please try again later. We're sorry for the inconvenience.

Is the sandbox having issues again?

Answer (score 0):

It may caused by unstable Sandbox environment. Please try again or you can try on live site.